# Dask: can't submit tasks to global client from separate multiprocessing.Process

Tags: python, dask, pyzmq

I have 2 processes: the first one on which I create the global distributed client; the second process is a web scraper, that should get the global client and submit tasks to it and when everything is done, it sends a message to another process to tell it that he can proceed.

```
from dask.distributed import Client, as_completed
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep
import zmq


def get(url) -> dict:
   # downloads data from url
   time.sleep(3)

   return data


def save(data) -> None:
    # saves data locally
    time.sleep(3)

    return None


def scraper(urls):
    # global client
    client = get_client()

    # zeromq socket
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
    socket.bind('tcp://*:port')

    while True:
        for future, result in as_completed([client.submit(get, url=url) for url in urls], with_results=True):
        save(data=result)
        socket.send_string('All job is done for this minute, proceed.')
        sleep(60)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    client = Client()

    s = Process(target=scraper, *args, **kwargs)
    s.start()
```

The problem is that from the scraper function I can get the global client (I see it correctly if I print it), but I can't submit to it any kind of task. The console doesn't print any error, it's just stuck without doing nothing. I think that the cause is that the scraper function is running on a saparate multiprocessing.Process.

Any solution or workaround? Thank you.

Comment: What's up with those functions which do nothing? `get()` returns `data`, which as far as I can tell is undefined.

Comment: get() basically is a scraper that downloads json files from web using the requests library; save() manipulates the json (dict) data and saves it locally. Just that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dask client holds open connections to the scheduler. Depending on how your systems creates new processes, you may get copies of the connections which point to nothing useful in the new process, or fail to transfer the client completely (it is not pickleable).

Instead, you should send the connection information to the child process

```
addr = c.scheduler_info()['address']
```

and in the target function do

```
client = Client(addr)
```

Comment: `client = Client(addr)` return the following error: `OSError: Timed out trying to connect to 'tcp://127.0.0.1:36047' after 10 s: Timed out trying to connect to 'tcp://127.0.0.1:36047' after 10 s: connect() didn't finish in time`. Instead, `client = get_client(addr)` works without returning errors, but still I can't submit new tasks from the separate processes, it remains stuck without printing anything or returning any error.

Comment: So? No solution?